# Hex color to rgb color not accurate?

Tags: php

I'm using php to convert from a hex color-value to an rgb color value. However when i look at the two colors they do not look the same?

I'm using the rgb value as a background color in a text to image script. Using php.

Any idea how to get the precise color in rgb?

The code has been included below.

```
    function hex2rgb($hex) {
         $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

          if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
              $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
              $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
              $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
          } else {
              $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
              $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
              $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
         }
     $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
       //return implode(",", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas
       return $rgb; // returns an array with the rgb values
      }
```

The Thing is that the colours do not match.

Thanks

Comment: How you convert these colors? Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

the code below can convert `#dfdfdf`  to `(239,239,239)`

```
<?php
     function hex2rgb( $colour ) {
     if ( $colour[0] == '#' ) {
    $colour = substr( $colour, 1 );
     }
     if ( strlen( $colour ) == 6 ) {
    list( $r, $g, $b ) = array( $colour[0] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[3], $colour[4] . $colour[5] );
     } elseif ( strlen( $colour ) == 3 ) {
    list( $r, $g, $b ) = array( $colour[0] . $colour[0], $colour[1] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[2] );
     } else {
     return false;
     }
    $r = hexdec( $r );
    $g = hexdec( $g );
    $b = hexdec( $b );
     return array( 'red' => $r, 'green' => $g, 'blue' => $b );
     }
     ?>
```